# How do I remove/delete an old super admin user?

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

I have googled this on the web and also searched for the answer on StackExchange but I can't find a clear set of instructions for removing and deleting a super admin user!

I'm performing some admin tasks on a multisite with 100+ sites and need to remove/clean up some old developer accounts within the dashboard.

I go to network > users and see a list of super admin and cannot remove any of them. I can disable their accounts (which is a logical first step).

Do I need to individually remove them from each of the 100+ sites and then I can remove their account from the WPMU? Alternatively, is there a quick/simple way to demote their role to subscriber from super admin?

Answer (score 23):

Oh I feel fairly stupid now. When looking at the user page again I noticed a checkbox for demoting the users access rights:

Super Admin - Grant this user super admin privileges for the Network.
Since unchecking that box, it appears that I can now remove/delete the user.

Comment: thank for leaving the answer instead of just saying "I found it"

Comment: you are not the only one, lol